# DBFlow 'count as'

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, android-sqlite, dbflow

I want to execute the following statement in [DBFlow](https://github.com/Raizlabs/DBFlow/):

```
SELECT SECTION_ID, COUNT(SECTION_ID) AS SECTION_COUNT FROM ARTICLES GROUP BY SECTION_ID ORDER BY SECTION_COUNT DESC
```

What I tried is:

```
Select(Article_Table.sectionId).from(Article.java).count(???) ...
```

The [Flow object](https://github.com/Raizlabs/DBFlow/blob/master/dbflow/src/main/java/com/raizlabs/android/dbflow/sql/language/From.java) has a `count()`method but it takes a [DatabaseWrapper](https://github.com/Raizlabs/DBFlow/blob/master/dbflow/src/main/java/com/raizlabs/android/dbflow/structure/database/DatabaseWrapper.java) as an argument which I frankly don't understand, I would have expected it to take a Table Column (i.e. [Property](https://github.com/Raizlabs/DBFlow/blob/master/dbflow/src/main/java/com/raizlabs/android/dbflow/sql/language/property/Property.java)).

Any ideas how I can do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add

```
Method.count()
```

inside your `Select()` statement

Example: `Select(Method.count()).from(Article.class).count();`